# The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value while accepting a Bid at Freelanc eengine Theme

Tags: wordpress, paypal

Am working on a Wordpress Theme called freelanceengine to setup my Paypal Escrow account. I have created API Credentials and Live APP ID from www.paypal-apps.com
While am creating the Live APP ID i was in contact with Paypal Technical team over the phone so that i don't make any mistake.

After all work is done and Approved at paypal i have given the exact Credentials at the Dashboard of my Wordpress theme and now its live for testings. Now when am trying to accept a Bid in my site am getting a Error : The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value.

I have tried googling and find a solution and now i landed here, Please note that am just a beginner with WP and Paypal. You can also test it by visiting my site www.savebpo.com

Thank you

Comment: I doubt the elements you provide will be sufficient to understand the exact cause of the problem. What have you tried so far to debug the application?

Comment: Did you make sure that you changed the payment mode in live mode ?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It was in Test mode and ai have changed it to Live and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. It was in Test mode and ai have changed it to Live and it worked.